# complex of psuedo-tensorial differential forms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $P(M,G)$ be a principal bundle. Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space (over $\mathbb{R}$). Let $\rho:G\rightarrow GL(V)$ be a representation.

> A $V$-valued differential $r$-form $\varphi$ on $P$ is said to be  *a
>   psuedo-tensorial $r$-form of type $(\rho,V)$*  if
>   $(R_a)^*\varphi=\rho(a^{-1}).\varphi$ for all $a\in G$; that is, 
>   $$(R_a^*\varphi)(p)(v_1,\cdots,v_r)=\rho(a^{-1})\big(\varphi(p)(v_1,\cdots,v_r)\big)$$
>   for all $a\in G$, $p\in P$ and $v_i\in T_pP$ with $1\leq i\leq r$.

Let $\varphi$ be a psuedo-tensorial differential $r$-form on $P$. Then, the usual exterior derivative $d\varphi$ is  a psuedo-tensorial differential $r+1$-form on $P$ (for reference, see Kobayashi and Nomizu, Volume $1$, page $76$). Thus, one can consider the complex $$\cdots\Omega_{(\rho,V)}^{r-1}(P)\xrightarrow{d}\Omega_{(\rho,V)}^r(P)\xrightarrow{d}\Omega_{(\rho,V)}^{r+1}(P)\rightarrow \cdots$$ of psuedo-tensorial forms of type $(\rho,V)$ on $P$. We can also consider the corresponding cohomology groups.

Question : Does choosing $(\rho, V)$ tactically and considering the complex of psuedo-tensorial forms and the corresponding cohomology groups give an extra insight about the principal bundle $P(M,G)$?

Side question : Only place I have seen psuedo-tensorial forms is when defining the curvature form $\Omega$. Given a connection $\Gamma\subseteq TP$ on the principal bundle $P(M,G)$, the corresponding connection form $\omega:P\rightarrow \Lambda^1_{\mathfrak{g}}T^*P$ is a psuedo-tensorial $1$-form on $P$ (of type $(ad,\mathfrak{g})$) and the corresponding curvature form $\Omega:P\rightarrow \Lambda^2_{\mathfrak{g}}T^*P$ is a tensorial  $2$-form on $P$. Are there other places where tensorial differential forms arise?